# How to replace images to font awesome in star rating?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, font-awesome

I have this star rating demo. Here, stars are displaying as images.

I want to use either font-awesome icons OR css for stars. Can anyone help me out? Code is attached. Please review and let me know. If anyone have any easier way to do that, please post your answers. I need to display some messages too on hover or click of stars.

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.starRating1 = 4;
    $scope.starRating2 = 5;
    $scope.starRating3 = 2;
    $scope.hoverRating1 = $scope.hoverRating2 = $scope.hoverRating3 = 0;

    $scope.click1 = function (param) {
        console.log('Click(' + param + ')');
    };

    $scope.mouseHover1 = function (param) {
        console.log('mouseHover(' + param + ')');
        $scope.hoverRating1 = param;
    };

    $scope.mouseLeave1 = function (param) {
        console.log('mouseLeave(' + param + ')');
        $scope.hoverRating1 = param + '*';
    };
}]);

app.directive('starRating', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            rating: '=',
            maxRating: '@',
            readOnly: '@',
            click: "&",
            mouseHover: "&",
            mouseLeave: "&"
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        template:
            "<div style='display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor:pointer;' ng-repeat='idx in maxRatings track by $index'> \
                    <i class='fa fa-star-o' aria-hidden='true' ng-Click='isolatedClick($index + 1)' \
                    ng-mouseenter='isolatedMouseHover($index + 1)' \
                    ng-mouseleave='isolatedMouseLeave($index + 1)'></i> \
            </div>",
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            if (!attrs.maxRating || (Number(attrs.maxRating) <= 0)) {
                attrs.maxRating = '5';
            };
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.maxRatings = [];

            for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.maxRating; i++) {
                $scope.maxRatings.push({});
            };

            $scope._rating = $scope.rating;

            $scope.isolatedClick = function (param) {
                if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

                $scope.rating = $scope._rating = param;
                $scope.hoverValue = 0;
                $scope.click({
                    param: param
                });
            };

            $scope.isolatedMouseHover = function (param) {
                if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

                $scope._rating = 0;
                $scope.hoverValue = param;
                $scope.mouseHover({
                    param: param
                });
            };

            $scope.isolatedMouseLeave = function (param) {
                if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

                $scope._rating = $scope.rating;
                $scope.hoverValue = 0;
                $scope.mouseLeave({
                    param: param
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
        <div class="alert alert-success"> <span class="label label-info">Star Rating: Read/Write</span>

            <div star-rating rating="starRating1" read-only="false" max-rating="10" click="click1(param)" mouse-hover="mouseHover1(param)" mouse-leave="mouseLeave1(param)"></div>
            <div> <span class="label label-primary">Star Rating: {{starRating1}}</span>
 <span class="label label-primary">Hover Rating: {{hoverRating1}}</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added font-awesome star to the example. but, not sure how to get hover and clicked state.

Comment: Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use **ui.bootstrap.rating**

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-star', stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'},
    {stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
    <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-warning': percent<30, 'label-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'label-success': percent>=70}" ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">{{percent}}%</span>

    <pre style="margin:15px 0;">Rate: <b>{{rate}}</b> - Readonly is: <i>{{isReadonly}}</i> - Hovering over: <b>{{overStar || "none"}}</b></pre>

    

    
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I use my own font instead of glyphicon?

Comment: You can just override the classes like below

`.glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.glyphicon-star {
  content: "\f005";
}`